# Distinguish between left and right shift keys using RAWINPUT

Tags: windows, winapi, input, raw-input

RAWINPUT provides two flags (`RI_KEY_E0` and `RI_KEY_E1`) to check whether the left or right version of a key is pressed. This works great for CTRL, but not for left and right shift. In fact, the flags are the same for both, and the VKey is also the same (`VK_SHIFT`). How can I find out which shift was pressed? I'm working on Windows 7. Interestingly, the flags/vkey values are exactly the same no matter which shift key I'm pressing.

Comment: Hmm, I have declarations for `VK_LSHIFT` and `VK_RSHIFT`. What operating system are you targeting/developing on? They've been available since at least Windows 2000.

Comment: Windows 7, and I only get VK_SHIFT, never the L/R variants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Windows 7, and I only get VK_SHIFT, never the L/R variants

Which is part of the explanation why this doesn't work the way you think it should do.  There's ancient history behind this.  The keyboard controller was redesigned for the IBM AT, again for the Enhanced keyboard.  It started sending out 0xe0 and 0xe1 prefixes for keys that were added to the keyboard layout.  Like the right Ctrl and Alt keys.

But keyboards *always* had two shift keys.  The original IBM PC didn't consider them special keys, they simply have a different scan code.  Which was maintained in later updates.  Accordingly, you don't get the RI_KEY_E0 or E1 flags for them.  You have to distinguish them by the RAWKEYBOARD.MakeCode value.  The left shift key has makecode 0x2a, the right key is 0x36.

Note that the left Ctrl and Alt keys don't have the flags either.  They match the corresponding keys on the old PC keyboard layout.  The description of the flags in the MSDN Library article is not very accurate.

Comment: Works great. Interestingly, I get RI_KEY_E0/E1 for left/right control and alt.

Comment: Hmm, odd.  I certainly don't, I tested it on my laptop before I posted.  Watch out for this, assume left if the flags aren't set.

Comment: I see no flags for left Ctrl and Alt, and E0 for right Ctrl and Alt. MakeCode is the same for both Ctrls and both Alts. Shift is different, it has no E0/E1 in any case, but differs in makecodes just as you answered. Thanks for your answer, it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish left-right SHIFT/CONTROL/ALT VK codes like this:

```cpp
 case WM_INPUT:
{
    HRAWINPUT dataHandle = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam);

    RAWINPUT input;
    UINT size = sizeof(input);

    ::GetRawInputData(dataHandle, RID_INPUT, &input, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    if (input.header.dwType != RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
        break;

    const RAWKEYBOARD& keyboard = input.data.keyboard;

    // Ignore key overrun state
    if (keyboard.MakeCode == KEYBOARD_OVERRUN_MAKE_CODE)
        return;

    // Ignore keys not mapped to any VK code
    // This effectively filters out scan code pre/postfix for some keys like PrintScreen.
    if (keyboard.VKey >= 0xff/*VK__none_*/)
        return;

    uint16_t scanCode = keyboard.MakeCode;

    // Scan codes could contain 0xe0 or 0xe1 one-byte prefix.
    // See https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf
    scanCode |= (keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_E0) ? 0xe000 : 0;
    scanCode |= (keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_E1) ? 0xe100 : 0;

    uint16_t vkCode = keyboard.VKey;
    switch (vkCode)
    {
    case VK_SHIFT:   // -> VK_LSHIFT or VK_RSHIFT
    case VK_CONTROL: // -> VK_LCONTROL or VK_RCONTROL
    case VK_MENU:    // -> VK_LMENU or VK_RMENU
        vkCode = LOWORD(MapVirtualKeyW(scanCode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX));
        break;
    }

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

This code should work at least from Vista.

But please note that gamedev programmers are usually manually mapping scancodes to internal game engine specific keycodes - because VK codes are tend to change on different keyboard layouts. For example if you use usual VK_W/VK_A/VK_S/VK_D for movement in QWERTY layout - it could turn into VK_Z/VK_Q/VK_S/VK_D in AZERTY keyboard layout. VK codes are primarily handy in Win32 GUI programming.

You can grab decent scancode<->USB HID Usage conversion table here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ui/events/keycodes/dom/dom_code_data.inc