# WM_INPUT is defective

Tags: c++, winapi, input, window

I want to catch the key presses send to my window in order to store each key's state, and distinguish between the left and right instances of the key, like `WM_LCONTROL` and `WM_RCONTROL`.

As `WM_KEYUP/DOWN` doesn't offer this functionality so i moved to raw input and i need to process `WM_INPUT`.

The problem is that the flags from the `RAWKEYBOARD` structure, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), don't work as they should.

When i press right control key, `RI_KEY_E0` is set which is for the left version of the 
key, and when i press left control, neither `RI_KEY_E0` nor `RI_KEY_E1` are set.
The alt key performs similarly, but i can workaround this problem, since left still provides different flags form the right key.

But for the left and right shift keys there aren't any flags set to distinguish the left version from the right version, so i can't do anything about them.

The virtual key code given when `WM_INPUT` arrives doesn't distinguish between left and right keys, and using `MapVirtualKey` on the scan code doesn't work either.

What's up with this unorthodox behavior of raw inputs?

Some code:

Registering:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;
rid.usUsagePage=0x01;
rid.usUsage=0x06;
rid.dwFlags=0; // I also tried RIDEV_APPKEYS,RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS,RIDEV_NOLEGACY, none fixed the problem
rid.hwndTarget=hwnd;
if(!RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid,1,sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)))
    ExitError("Failed to register raw input device",true); //displays error and exits
```

Processing WM_INPUT:

```
case WM_INPUT:
{    
    RAWINPUT rw;
    UINT sz=sizeof(rw);
    u_char vk; //used to make code shorter
    USHORT flag; //used to make code shorter

    if(!GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lparam,RID_INPUT,&rw,&sz,sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)))
        break;

    vk=rw.data.keyboard.VKey;
    flag=rw.data.keyboard.Flags;

    ...Process flags and save the actual key pressed in vk...

    keys[vk]=!(flag&RI_KEY_BREAK); //save key's state
    break;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinguish between left and right shift keys using RAWINPUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920301/distinguish-between-left-and-right-shift-keys-using-rawinput)

Comment: "WM_INPUT is defective" : I doubt it.

Comment: @John Dibling they don't work as they are documented, read the link that Hans Passant gave for details, so it defective. Also, the issues described in that question are slightly different from mines, so the problem isn't even constant, distributing a application working with this may have different issues on different systems which is terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_KEYDOWN/-UP` does deliver the info you want ,you just have to read the decription in MSDN.

check bit 24 of the lParam parameter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i ignored it in the past. Apparently it sets the extension flag only on control key, on shift it doesn't but provides different scan code so i can use MapVirtualKey to distinguish between left and right shift

Comment: Although this answer takes care of the problem of distinguishing left and right keys, it does not address the question actually asked here, which is about interpreting wm_Input.

Comment: I said "WM_KEYUP/DOWN doesn't offer this functionality so i moved to raw inputs...", so i care about functionality, not method, and this answer helped me to solve the need for proper input in a simpler matter; using raw input needs some extra code which i would prefer not to have

Answer (score 0):

[`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) and [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281.aspx) send you `VK_CONTROL` in `wParam` when either control key is pressed. To find out whether or not the right-hand control key is pressed, read bit 24 of `lParam`, as described in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx). Bit 24 is described like this:

> Indicates whether the key is an extended key, such as the right-hand ALT and CTRL keys that appear on an enhanced 101- or 102-key keyboard. The value is 1 if it is an extended key; otherwise, it is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for RAWKEYBORAD is wrong. The constants `RI_KEY_E0` and `RI_KEY_E1` do not apply to *left* or *right* versions of the keys; instead they apply to scancode extensions.

The virtual-key values that are dumped into `RAWKEYBOARD::VKey` refer to the general purpose values like `VK_SHIFT`, `VK_CONTROL`, or `VK_MENU`.

To correct this it is possible to makes use of the `RAWKEYBOARD::VKey` and `RAWKEYBOARD::MakeCode` members. Different keys differentiate between different sides in different ways:

- For the shift keys reassign using `MapVirtualKey` and passing `RAWKEYBOARD::MakeCode` and `MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX` as parameters, and
- For both the control and alt keys map based on the `RI_KEY_E0` flag (like `key.VKey = key.Flags & RI_KEY_E0 ? VK_RCONTROL : VK_LCONTROL` for example).

The values you want from the numpad are depend on whether you treat NUMLK as being on or off.

I had the same confusion as you and I'm still learning about how keyboards transfer data but I'm finding [this](http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/properly-handling-keyboard-input/) blog post on *Molecular Musings* particularly helpful. The reasoning behind this method can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920881/2379628) post.

Comment: I wanted to link you to all the correct documentation but apparently I'm not allowed...

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish left-right SHIFT/CONTROL/ALT VK codes like this:

```cpp
 case WM_INPUT:
{
    HRAWINPUT dataHandle = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam);

    RAWINPUT input;
    UINT size = sizeof(input);

    ::GetRawInputData(dataHandle, RID_INPUT, &input, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    if (input.header.dwType != RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
        break;

    const RAWKEYBOARD& keyboard = input.data.keyboard;

    // Ignore key overrun state
    if (keyboard.MakeCode == KEYBOARD_OVERRUN_MAKE_CODE)
        return;

    // Ignore keys not mapped to any VK code
    // This effectively filters out scan code pre/postfix for some keys like PrintScreen.
    if (keyboard.VKey >= 0xff/*VK__none_*/)
        return;

    uint16_t scanCode = keyboard.MakeCode;

    // Scan codes could contain 0xe0 or 0xe1 one-byte prefix.
    // See https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf
    scanCode |= (keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_E0) ? 0xe000 : 0;
    scanCode |= (keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_E1) ? 0xe100 : 0;

    uint16_t vkCode = keyboard.VKey;
    switch (vkCode)
    {
    case VK_SHIFT:   // -> VK_LSHIFT or VK_RSHIFT
    case VK_CONTROL: // -> VK_LCONTROL or VK_RCONTROL
    case VK_MENU:    // -> VK_LMENU or VK_RMENU
        vkCode = LOWORD(MapVirtualKeyW(scanCode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX));
        break;
    }

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

This code should work at least from Vista.