# Dealing with Raw Input - Undefined virtual key printouts

Tags: c++, winapi, input

I'm making an input system based upon the Raw Input API. However, I'm having trouble distinguishing between left/right shift. Additionally, there are some printouts that I am unable to understand, and would appreciate some clarification!

I'm printing out the input keycode with the following code segment

```
case WM_INPUT:
{
    // Forward declaration
    RAWINPUT     input;
    HRAWINPUT    handle = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam);
    UINT         szData = sizeof(RAWINPUT);

    // Fetch the current input
    GetRawInputData(handle, RID_INPUT, &input, &szData, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    // Determine input type and update accordingly
    switch (input.header.dwType)
    {
        case RIM_TYPEMOUSE:     Input::UpdateMouse(input.data.mouse, WindowSystem::WindowHandler);      break;
        case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:  Input::UpdateKeyboard(input.data.keyboard);                             break;

        default:                                                                                        break;
    }

    break;
}
```

and

```
void Input::UpdateKeyboard(const RAWKEYBOARD & data)
{
    // Fetch the current key code
    const auto & keyCode = data.VKey;

    std::cout << "Getting key: " << std::hex << (unsigned short)keyCode << std::endl;
// Ensure the virtual key is within the range of 
// virtual keys that we are dealing with
if (keyCode < (numKeys) )
{
    const auto  & Flag = data.Flags;                                        // Reference to input map key state

    // Update the input map according to the raw input key state
    // 1. Key pressed
    if      (Flag == (RI_KEY_MAKE  | RI_KEY_E0) || (Flag == (RI_KEY_MAKE)))
    { 
        SetKeystateDown(keyCode); 
    }

    // 2. Key not pressed
    else if ( (Flag == (RI_KEY_BREAK | RI_KEY_E0)) || (Flag == (RI_KEY_BREAK)) )
    { 
        SetKeystateUp(keyCode); 
    }
}
```

While other keys like the keyboard alphabet letters give the correct keycode printouts, keys on the right side of the keyboard give me some weird printouts.

i.e. Keyboard Q prints out 0x51, while right control prints out 0xff AND 0x11

Would appreciate any help on this topic! Thanks!

Comment: 0xFF is not a valid virtual key code, where are you getting that from? 0x11 is `VK_CONTROL`, which doesn't differentiate between left/right (left is 0xA2 `VK_LCONTROL` and right is 0xA3 `VK_RCONTROL`). If all you ever get for CTRL is `VK_CONTROL` then use the `ScanCode` (or at least the `RI_KEY_E(0|1)` flags) to differentiate left/right if needed ([left/right SHIFT is handled different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920301/)). The way you are testing `Flags` is wrong, though. Use this instead: `if (Flag & RI_KEY_MAKE) { /*key is down*/ } else if (Flag & RI_KEY_BREAK) { /*key is up*/ }`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the if condition! The referenced link doesn't seem to provide any insight on how to deal with left/right shift though. I've tried testing with the RI_KEY_E(0|1) but it doesn't seem to work with shift key. I've also printed out the flags and keycode, but they both have the same printouts. Any hints in the right direction?

Comment: Just realized I could employ MapVirtualKey with data.MakeCode! Thanks for the help thus far anyway, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: the link I provided explains *exactly* how to differentiate left/right SHIFT: "*You have to distinguish [shift] by the RAWKEYBOARD.MakeCode value. The left shift key has makecode 0x2a, the right key is 0x36.*"